# Fazer upload de arquivo com javascript puro, (crawler) inputar arquivo

Tags: javascript, html, input, javascript-eventos, web-crawler

Eu estou crawleando uma página na web e chega um momento em que preciso fazer upload de um arquivo, este crawler é para testar um sistema. O que eu preciso fazer é com o javascript puro inputar um documento na seguinte pagina:

```
<label for="avatar">Choose a profile picture:</label>

<input type="file"
       id="avatar" name="avatar"
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

Alguém sabe como poderia fazer isso ?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você deseja um script, que acesse essa URL e que envie um arquivo predeterminado ao servidor que hospeda essa página, é isso que deseja?

Comment: Não tem como inputar arquivos da máquina do cliente, se isso fosse possivel seria uma das maiores brechas de segurança que um navegador teria.

Comment: Faltou o principal, o código que você já tem! Está usando o que? Puppeteer? PhantomJS? Selenium? Enfim, precisa do código que você já tem.

Comment: Eu uso uma classe que foi desenvolvida com dryscrap , eu já tenho o código que navega na pagina e preenche campos normais , essa classe que utilizo tem uma função que permite executar javascript puro na tela, esse javascript que utilizo para preencher os campos, contudo simular um arquivo está complicado, com puppeteer eu consigo subir pois já tem uma função própria dele.

Comment: No puppeteer seria assim ```  var findelement = await page.$("#file"); 
                        await findelement.uploadFile("teste.pdf"); //Caminho do arquivo relativo ao script. ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal eu consegui resolver.

Basicamente o que tive que fazer foi realizar uma requisição ajax sobre o arquivo que queria inputar forçando a requisição retornar um objeto bluble (que é o arquivo no formato binário).

Após isso com esse arquivo em mãos verifiquei a função de upload que era chamada no upload, chamei essa função passando os parâmetros e meu arquivo binário. Com isso ele foi pro servidor.

Agradeço o apoio.

Comment: Seria interessante postar o código na resposta.